# Authorisation header is getting removed when api call reached the Service

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, xmlhttprequest, authorization

There is xhr call from UI to Backend service,

In the request we clearly see that `Authorization` header is having the jwt
but when the api call received the backend service, there is no Authorization header.

```
   const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); xhr.open('PUT', url, true);
 
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwtToken}`);
  xhr.setRequestHeader(
    'Cache-Control',
    'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
  );
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Expires', '0');
  xhr.send();`
```

In the API, when we try to validate the Authorization header, it is not available.

It is happening intermittently. could not able to trace the root cause

Comment: Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) under which circumstances XMLHttpRequests can contain credentials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if "url" is a different origin than where the web app was served, you need to add this code before sending:

```
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

If that doesn't work, it's probably a problem with the server.

If the server you are using happens to be Apache:

by default it will strip the Authorization header, so you will have to add this to the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```